# Term for function that interprets arguments by type rather than order?

Tags: function, paradigms

Is there a term for a function that interprets arguments based on their type rather than the order in which they are passed? For example, the JavaScript function

```
function multiplier(text, iterations){
    // Do some type checking of text and iterations here if necessary
    var result="";
    for(var iteration=0;iteration<iterations;iteration++)
        result+=text;
    return result;
}
```

returns a string of `iterations` copies of `text`

```
console.log( multiplier("abc", 3) ); // --> abcabcabc
```

but interprets arguments based on order. Modifying it to ignore order but use type checking instead:

```
function multiplier(){
    // Do arguments.length and any other checking here if necessary
    var text, iterations, result="";
    for(var index=0;index<arguments.length;index++){
        if(arguments[index] instanceof String || typeof arguments[index] == "string")
            text=arguments[index];
        if(arguments[index] instanceof Number || typeof arguments[index] == "number")
            iterations=arguments[index];
    }
    for(var iteration=0;iteration<iterations;iteration++)
        result+=text;
    return result;
}
```

returns the same result for the same `text` and `iterations` values regardless of the order in which they are passed, provided that they are a string and a number:

```
console.log( multiplier("abc", 3) ); // --> abcabcabc
console.log( multiplier(3, "abc") ); // --> abcabcabc
```

The `multiplier` function could be implemented via overloading in a statically-typed language like C++ to accept all argument order permutations, but it could also be implemented in dynamically-typed languages like Python which don't *truly* support overloading.

Is there a term for a function or paradigm that either partially or totally ignores argument order and instead determines argument purpose based on type?

Comment: IMO, for all practical purposes this is indistinguishable from overloading. In JS-land, though, I don't really know.

Comment: Overloading somehow doesn't feel right. The argument types and arity are the same... It technically is overloading (or the JavaScript equivalent of "overloading"ishness). I guess I'm asking about this application of overloading-like behaviour i.e. argument order is ignored.